# Function to add sum based on one or more arguments in pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

I am new to pandas and python.

My DataFrame looks like this:

```
             Search query  Impressions  Clicks     Word
0           iPhone X 2019        10000      50   iPhone
1           iPhone X 2019        10000      50        X
2           iPhone X 2019        10000      50     2019
3            iPhoneX 2019           15      64  iPhoneX
4            iPhoneX 2019           15      64     2019
5               iPhone 11           60      87   iPhone
6               iPhone 11           60      87       11
7              Nokia 3310          444      61    Nokia
8              Nokia 3310          444      61     3310
9   Nokia 3310 best phone            1      30    Nokia
10  Nokia 3310 best phone            1      30     3310
11  Nokia 3310 best phone            1      30     best
12  Nokia 3310 best phone            1      30    phone
```

I am trying to write a function that would add `Impressions` and `Clicks` based on the `Word` column.

For example I want to know how many clicks word `Nokia` had so I would add up `Clicks` value from rows 7 and 9. Then I would like to know how many `Clicks` were when word is `Nokia` and `3310`.

What I've tried:

```
def f(column, *args):
    #result = df[column].sum() where df['Word'] = args
```

The logic is that I would pass the first argument to define which column I am trying to calculate and then define word or words to base the calculations on.

Thank you for your suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is possible pass list and then filter by [`Series.isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.isin.html):

```
def f(column, v):
    return df.loc[df['Word'].isin(v), column].sum()

print (f('Impressions', ['Nokia']))
445

print (f('Clicks', ['Nokia','3310']))
182
```

EDIT: For possible return sum of all values is possible chain by `|` inverted emty list, because `bool([])` return `False`:

```
def f(column, v=[]):
    return df.loc[df['Word'].isin(v) | (not bool(v)), column].sum()

print (f('Impressions', ['Nokia']))
445

print (f('Impressions'))
31042
```

Comment: How could I update this function to be able to accept no second argument and take all dataframe into consideration? Like using `*args`, but `isin()` method needs to take an argument though.

Comment: @JonasPalačionis - One possible solution (maybe exist better one, not sure) is use `def f(column, v=[]):
    return df.loc[df['Word'].isin(v), column].sum() if v!= [] else df[column].sum()`

Comment: and then `print (f('Impressions'))` - sum all values of column

Comment: @JonasPalačionis - added better solution, answer was edited.